# Multi Select Category Attribute not saving

Tags: category, attributes, multiselect-attribute, ce-1.9.0.0

I'm using Magento Community 1.9.0.0.

I have programmatically created a custom category attribute which is a multi select. The attribute can be seen in my admin category section. When i select any values - whether it's one or more and press save i get a successful saved message but the values never save.

I then also tried an extension which creates category attributes. This had the same issue. When i contacted support they said

***Category entity does not support multi selection so this type of attribute will not work with category.***

Is this true? Can multi select not work on category attributes on CE-1.9?

Here is the code i was using to create it programmatically:

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;
$attribute  = array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'label'=> 'Room Type',
    'input' => 'multiselect',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'default' => "",
    'group' => "General Information",
    'option' => array ( 
        'value' => array(
            'kitchen' => array('Kitchen'), 
            'bedroom' => array('Bedroom'), 
            'bathroom' => array('Bathroom'), 
            'loft' => array('Loft'), 
            'basement' => array('Basement'), 
            'lounge' => array('Lounge')
        ) 
    )

);
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'room_type', $attribute);
$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: Did the answer below work? Did you find an answer? Please update.

Comment: Found the answer in my case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19826786/cant-save-multiselect-attribute-on-magento

Answer (score 4):

Well first it seems that there is an obvious error with `$installer->startSetup();` missing near the start, then you may also need to define the backend used for the attribute in order to save it:

```
'backend'           => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',
```

Otherwise instead of:

```
$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;
```

i would try to use:

```
$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('default_setup');
```

My two cents hoping it helps you if still needed. :)

the modified code:

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('default_setup');
$installer->startSetup();

$attribute  = array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'label'=> 'Room Type',
    'input' => 'multiselect',
    'backend' => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'default' => "",
    'group' => "General Information",
    'option' => array ( 
        'value' => array(
            'kitchen' => array('Kitchen'), 
            'bedroom' => array('Bedroom'), 
            'bathroom' => array('Bathroom'), 
            'loft' => array('Loft'), 
            'basement' => array('Basement'), 
            'lounge' => array('Lounge')
        ) 
    )
);

$installer->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'room_type', $attribute);
$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: What if, I am creating a attribute with a 3rd party extension? like Attribute Manager For category attribute? then how i would make it save the options?